# android button in class

Tags: android, button

All i want to do is to have a class that creates dynamically a button and fills it with the text 'tarr' automatically. So i generated a new class and wrote the following in it:

```
import android.widget.Button;

public class FloatButton {
    Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setText("tarr");
}
```

in my main activity it should make an object of this class. So i wrote this in the activity (snippet):

```
...

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FloatButton myButton = new FloatButton();
}
```

Sadly this gives me some mistakes marked. The mistake i don't realy understand is why the 'this' is marked. Can you tell me the problem?

Comment: Create a constructor in FloatButton with a parameter of type Context. Store this in a field. Finally instead of using this use the Context variable

Comment: Can you please add the error logcat output please :) ?

Comment: @MalteseFalcon the code wont compile at all.

Comment: before Android take a look at Java basics: Creating classes, extending classes, etc. It's better to go step by step.

Comment: Check my answer. For the future, make a habit of providing the full logcat errors, even if it does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending `this` to the `Button` constructor method, you are not sending a
valid `Context`, but your `FloatButton` object.

[Android Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

What you can do is :

```
   public class FloatButton {
        private Context _context;

        public FloatButton(Context context) {
          this._context = context;
        }
        public createButton() {
          Button mButton = new Button(_context);
          mButton.setText("tarr");
        }
    }
```

PS : Why are you trying to create a button in a separate class, and not directly in your activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a button dynamically and then add it to your activity.
The thing you are doing wrong is obviously not providing any context and two, you are not adding it to your activity's layout without which you will not be able to actually 'display' the button.
Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a function in the FloatButton class which receives a context and returns a button object as:

   ```
    public Button createNew(Context c){
    Button b = new Button(c);
    b.setText("tarr");
    return b;
   ```

   }
2. In your main class, create a FloatButton object and call the createNew function as:

> ```
> FloatButton fb = new FloatButton();
> Button button = fb.createNew(this);
> ```

This will give you a button object which you then have to add to your layout

3. Now you need to declare the mandatory layout parameters which are height and width. Do it as:

> ```
> LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
> LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
> ```

4. Get your activity's primary layout (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) as:

> LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);

where layout_main is the id of your layout

5. Finally add your button to the layout and set its layout parameters as:

> ll.addView(button, lp);

Though I would NOT recommend doing such a thing because you can replace the FloatButton class creation and instantiate using a simple `Button button = new Button(this)` in your main class itself. So, it is very redundant unless you want to do several customizations to your button in the FloatButton class itself like making it a different color or something and creating the button several times at several places.